# Test fails on import of react-bootstrap component

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, jestjs

I am trying to test some React components which are using react-bootstrap.

For some reason the import of a component coming from react-bootstrap will fail with this error:

```
FAIL test\App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\Documents\projects\koreanbuildsoverwolf2\node_modules\react-bootstrap\es\DropdownButton.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _objectWithoutProperties from 'babel-runtime/helpers/objectWithoutProperties';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      2 | import React from "react";
      3 | import "./LoginComponent.css";
    > 4 | import DropdownButton from "react-bootstrap/es/DropdownButton";
      5 | import MenuItem from "react-bootstrap/es/MenuItem";
      6 | import BackendFactory from "../../util/BackendFactory";
      7 | import GlobalState from "../../GlobalState";

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/subcomponents/LoginComponent.jsx:4:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/IndexComponent.jsx:6:23)
```

I tried this with both mocha and jest, both result in the same error message.

My Jest config is:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/test/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/test/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
```

Comment: Getting a similar error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I changed my setup quite a bit. I am running my tests now inside of puppeteer headless chrome and starting up webpack dev server programmaticly for the tests. 

It works pretty good, I also managed to do some mocking, by abusing localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding jest.disableAutomock();